# Assigning values to objects in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, oop, object

How to assign values to objects in `foreach` loop. 
Code is below:

```
using System;

namespace WorkingWithClasses
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        //create 5 player objects
        Player[] players = new Player[5];
        //assigning a value to a player brings null reference exception error:
        foreach(Player player in players)
        {
            player.Skill = 5;
        }


        float skillSum = 0;
        foreach(Player player in players)
        {
            skillSum += player.Skill;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(skillSum);
    }
}
class Player
{
    public float Skill { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question is not clear - it's *just* code apart from the title. Even the comment doesn't say *what* exception you're receiving. I suspect it's a NullReferenceException, in which case you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. For more guidance on asking a good Stack Overflow question, please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: What exception error ur getting. Try to assign `5.0F` like that

Comment: @sriharsha: There's an implicit conversion from `int` to `float` - that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every "Player" in your players array is not initialized. Try with this for loop instead of the foreach loop where you are getting the null reference:

```
for (var i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
{
    players[i] = new Player() { Skill = 5 };
}
```

You can also use this, however it's slower than iterating through the array with a for loop:

```
using System.Linq;

players = Enumerable.Repeat(new Player() { Skill = 5 }, 5).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer solved my problem.
And yes it was a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your players instance object since you are *creating array holder.*

Replace `Player[] players = new Player[5];` with

`Player[] players  = Enumerable.Repeat(new Player(), 5).ToArray();`